# Deleting duplicate complex numbers from array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have an array which consists of complex numbers. But some elements of array are repeated and I would like to delete the repeated elements. So if my array is :

```
[287.51064 +91.59481j 287.51066 +91.59486j 635.2268  +60.25797j  635.22683 +60.25794j 827.34355+107.88367j]
```

I would like to get a new array with following elements:

```
[287.51064+91.59481 635.2268+60.25797  827.34355+107.88367j]
```

I tried using np.unique function. But it didn't work.

How can it be done?

Comment: `(635.2268 + 60.25797j)` and `(635.22683 + 60.25794j)` are not the same number. Are they?

Comment: You should double check, your array doesn't have any duplicates.

Comment: @RiccardoBucco. My program generates this array. I want to consider only upto 3 decimals. And for imaginary part, I have same number upto 3 decimals. Hence I want to delete duplicate elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```
lst = [287.51064 + 91.59481j, 287.51066 + 91.59486j,
       635.2268 + 60.25797j,  635.22683 + 60.25794j,
       827.34355 + 107.88367j]
result = list(set(round(x.real, 3) + round(x.imag, 3) * 1j for x in lst))
```

Output:

```
[(287.511+91.595j), (827.344+107.884j), (635.227+60.258j)]
```